# ARCore – How do I add a specific object position to an ARAnchor?

Tags: java, position, anchor, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to add a specific object position to the anchor without tapping.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but no luck so far.  My understanding is that I need to call `session.createAnchor()` with a `Pose` object that in turn is created using translation/rotation info.

Comment: Thank you for advicing  me.I will run it according to your advice．

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code to add a specific object's position to an ARAnchor:

```
float[] position = { 0, 0, -2.5 };
float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };

Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
Anchor myAnchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));
anchorNode = new AnchorNode(myAnchor);
anchorNode.setRenderable(myModel);

anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Hope this helps.